# Left float image within a <li> Chrome issue

Tags: google-chrome, css-float

I was trying to create a ordered list which contains a left float image + a link for each li.

It works as expected in IE9 and FF, but not on IE8 nor Chrome.

It was a very straight forward stuff like this

```
<li><img style="float:left" src=".." /><a href="..">some text</a></li>
```

I am new here so I can't attach screenshots, but I will describe the issue:

It works as expected in IE9 and FF, but on Chrome the list number (1. 2. 3.) overlaps the image. Or you can look at it this way: the image floats to the left of the  <li>, covering the list number.

What could be the problem? I am using very basic CSS and HTML and have searched the site for possible solution.

My HTML code is like this

```
<li><a href="/v4/Profile/0"><img class="smallAvatar" src="/v4/thumb.axd/30_0/DA1D9A43075B47A1BAE73076E8D7867A.jpg"></a>
    <a href="/Message/390638-Mind-Game">Mind Game</a><br />
    <span class="msgInfo">(8 Replies)</span></li>
```

The image is an avatar, so it is taller than text. I want to have the avatar floated to the left and have 2 lines of text on its right. I am not sure if there is another way to accomplish this without a left float

Comment: Are you trying to use an image for the `li`? You can use `list-style-image:url('sourse')` to set an image as the list style. You can post your code which will help us understand your question better.

Comment: @neo108 I wasn't trying to do that. I want to display a image and a few lines of text on the right. I will post my code above again but it is not that different from what I have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the very same problem in Chrome and fixed it by putting my li content into a div. So your code would end up like this:

```
<li><div><a href="/v4/Profile/0"><img class="smallAvatar" src="/v4/thumb.axd/30_0/DA1D9A43075B47A1BAE73076E8D7867A.jpg"></a>
    <a href="/Message/390638-Mind-Game">Mind Game</a><br />
    <span class="msgInfo">(8 Replies)</span></div></li>
```

That way the dot or the number of your list is in front of the image and not overlapping the image anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want the float?

This works for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/ShStb/

EDIT: I would try using [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp).

Check out the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ShStb/2/

I changed the elements' `vertical-align` to these values:

```
ol li img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
ol li a {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

​

Comment: I added some more explanation why i want to float above.

Answer (score 0):

the `<ol> or <ul>` tags are stringently required in Chrome to work everything fine

Answer (score 0):

Use float property only if required. It is normally used to solve alignment issues across browsers.
Instead try to give margins to ur image and text. If nothing works your way then you could use a small Javascript tweak to solve the Chrome issue

Put this in your when your page loads

```
if(window.chrome != undefined)
{
    //remove float and add some margin image/text
}
```

Comment: You should avoid using browser sniffing!